# To find the conditions for which a complex valued function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let F be an entire complex valued function on a complex plane & suppose that F=u+iv where u & v are real and imaginary parts respectively. Then F is constant if

1) {u(x,y)/z=x+iy in $C$} is bounded.

2) {v(x,y)/z=x+iy in $C$} is bounded

3){u(x,y)+v(x,y)/z=x+iy in $C$} is bounded

4) {$u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)$/z=x+iy in $C$} is bounded

I know that options 1), 2), 4) are correct ones.
What about option 3)?

I am getting almost all options right. Please help me to get correct options.

Comment: So the 3) option is correct as well? Sorry but I am not getting the purpose of hint

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $u + v = \text{Re}((1-i) F)$.

Comment: I need a justification for 4th option . I know that |f| is constant implies f is constant. But |f|=$(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ then what about $u^2+v^2$?

Comment: If $u^2 + v^2 = |F|^2$ is bounded, then so is $|F|$.